# MySQL - Trying to get multiple rows matching duplicate foreign keys as additional columns

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-workbench

I have a database with the following two tables:

```
+------------+-------+---------+
| customer_id| name  | surname |  
+------------+-------+---------+  
| 123        | Bob   | Johnson |  
| 124        | Alice | Smith   |  
| 125        | Fred  | Rogers  |  
+------------+-------+---------+

+------------+-------------+--------------+------------+  
| address_id | customer_id | address_1    | address_2  |  
+------------+-------------+--------------+------------+  
| 1          |     123     | 123 A Street | Oneville   |  
| 2          |     124     | 321 B Street | Twoville   |  
| 3          |     124     | 42  C Street | Threeville |  
| 4          |     125     | 23  D Street | Fourville  |  
+------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to use a query to get the additional rows with the same customer ID from the address table into a format like this with the extra addresses added onto the row:

```
+-------------+---------------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------+  
| customer_id | customer_name | address_1    | address_2  |  address_3   | address_4  |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------+  
| 123         |     Bob       | 123 A Street | Oneville   |              |            |
| 124         |     Alice     | 321 B Street | Twoville   | 42  C Street | Threeville |
| 125         |     Fred      | 23  D Street | Fourville  |              |            |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

Currently my (simplified) query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    c.name AS 'customer_name',
    a.address_1,
    a.address_2,
FROM
    customer c
LEFT JOIN 
    address a ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id
GROUP BY a.customer_id
```

Based on what I've already found on here, I've tried adding a subquery to do it, but I don't think I understand them well enough to get it to work as intended.

Also, I would like to thank the contributors to this site for getting me though the extremely convoluted product database that I exported before this. Aren't website migrations fun?

Comment: What if a customer has 10 different addresses ? You expect 20 columns for that customer ?

Comment: Based on the website that I'm moving them to, they can only have two (Billing and Shipping) so I'm just selecting the first two addresses. That said, there are very few customers with more than two.

Comment: And how do we decide, which two addresses to pick, in case of more than 2 addresses. Do you really want to solve this in SQL; while such data display requirements can be more efficiently solved in application code (eg: C++, Java, PHP etc)

Comment: Maybe the next address_id? I'm afraid I'm stuck doing it with SQL since I don't know any application code other than some very (very!) basic PHP.  EDIT: I've just manually removed the customer addresses where there are more than two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, such data display related requirements should be generally solved using application code (eg: PHP, C++, Java, etc). However, based on your [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278499/mysql-trying-to-get-multiple-rows-matching-duplicate-foreign-keys-as-additiona#comment93440144_53278499), you need to do it with SQL only. Moreover, you are confirming that you are concerned with at-most 2 addresses of a customer.

In MySQL version < 8.0.2, we can [emulate](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) using [User-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), we will get all the addresses of a customer. It is important to get the data in a particular order in this subquery, so that outer subquery can utilize it for calculating row number values within a partition of `customer_id` correctly.

In the outer subquery, we will assign row number conditionally using `CASE..WHEN` expressions. In the outermost subquery, we will do conditional aggregation over a group of `customer_id`. `address_1` and `address_2` will be determined when the row number is 1; and `address_3` and `address_4` will be determined when the row number is 2

```
SELECT 
  dt2.customer_id, 
  dt2.customer_name, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN dt2.row_no = 1 THEN dt2.address_1 END) AS address_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN dt2.row_no = 1 THEN dt2.address_2 END) AS address_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN dt2.row_no = 2 THEN dt2.address_1 END) AS address_3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN dt2.row_no = 2 THEN dt2.address_2 END) AS address_4
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    @rn := CASE WHEN @cid = dt.customer_id THEN @rn + 1
                ELSE 1
           END AS row_no, 
    @cid := dt.customer_id AS customer_id, 
    dt.customer_name, 
    dt.address_1, 
    dt.address_2
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      c.customer_id,
      c.name AS 'customer_name',
      a.address_1,
      a.address_2 
    FROM
      customer c
    LEFT JOIN 
      address a ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id
    ORDER BY c.customer_id, a.address_id  -- this ordering is important
  ) AS dt
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cid := 0, @rn := 0) AS user_init_vars -- initialize variables
) AS dt2
GROUP BY dt2.customer_id, dt2.customer_name 
ORDER BY dt2.customer_id
```

Comment: Thank you, @Madhur! That works perfectly! I appreciate the explanation and the links as this is far more complex than what I would have been able to come up with alone.

Comment: @nova happy to help :) Hope the queries make sense. You can try to understand it, starting from the inner most subquery. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Hi Madhur, I'm hoping you might be able to help me again with this. How would I adapt this to get (according to the example I gave) all addresses - up to 33! - rather than just two? I thought of manually iterating the row numbers in the max function but I figure there's probably a more elegant solution for it.

Comment: @sol well my recommendation is to do this in application code instead. Using SQL to generate dynamic no of columns is not something I would recommend

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know where to even start with that, I'm afraid.

Comment: @sol ok try to setup your sample data covering the case upto 33 columns in DB fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/  I will give it a try